# Google cloud storage client with remote api on local client

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to use the google remote api on my app engine project to upload local files to my app's default cloud storage bucket.

I have configured my app.yaml to have remote api on. I'm able to access my bucket and upload/access files from it.  I run my local python console and try to write to the bucket with the following code:

```
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
import cloudstorage

def auth_func():
  return ('user@gmail.com', '*******')

remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi('my-app-id', '/_ah/remote_api', auth_func,'my-app-id.appspot.com')
filename = "/"+app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()+ "/myfile.txt"
gcs_file = cloudstorage.open(filename,'w',content_type='text/plain',options={'x-goog-meta-foo': 'foo','x-goog-meta-bar': 'bar'})
```

I see the following reponse:

```
WARNING:root:suspended generator urlfetch(context.py:1214) raised DownloadError(Unable to fetch URL: http://None/_ah/gcs/my-app-id.appspot.com/myfile.txt)
```

Notice the

```
http://None/_ah/gcs.....
```

I don't think **None** should be part of the url.  Is there an issue with the GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient, v1.9.0.0?  I'm also using Google App Engine 1.9.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: `app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()` is not getting set so it seems. Are you able to confirm it?

Comment: Yes, it returns my-app-id.appspot.com

Comment: Try changing `filename = "/%s/myfile.txt" % app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()`

Comment: And where you have 'my-app-id' you _actually_ have your app id, correct?

Comment: Yes, ids/usernames/passwords/etc everything has been double checked.

Comment: As far a I know, the main purpose of the Remote API is to interact with the datastore. You can interact locally with Cloud Storage without it.

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Storage client does not respect remote_api_stub and considers you are running script locally

```py
os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = 'Development (remote_api)/1.0'
```

or even

```py
os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = ''
```

will help.

The function, checking your environment from `common.py`

```py
def local_run():
  """Whether we should hit GCS dev appserver stub."""
  server_software = os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE')
  if server_software is None:
    return True
  if 'remote_api' in server_software:
    return False
  if server_software.startswith(('Development', 'testutil')):
    return True
  return False
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to upload a local text file to a specific bucket. I do not think what you're doing will work.

The alternative would be to ditch the RemoteAPI and upload it using the [Cloud Storage API](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/?hl=fr).